# Gnu assembler gives unexpected memory operand

Tags: assembly, x86-64, gnu, gnu-assembler, yasm

The GNU assembler gives an unexpected memory operand when assembling Intel syntax code.

I have reduced my bug to one single lonely line of code, and for the last three days I've tried anything to understand why the GNU assembler yields something that I cannot understand. I know this must (or should) be trivial, but I'm at a loss.

The following text resided in the file code.asm:

```
.intel_syntax noprefix
.global somecode
somecode: 
    int 3
    mov        rax,qword [rcx]
    ret
.att_syntax
```

Assembling and disassembling code.asm with:

```
as code.asm -o code1.obj -64 
objdump -Mintel -d code1.obj > code1.asm
```

The content of code1.asm (with the disassembled code) is:

```
code1.obj:     file format pe-x86-64
Disassembly of section .text:
0000000000000000 <somecode>:
   0:   cc                      int3 
   1:   48 8b 41 08             mov    rax,QWORD PTR [rcx+0x8]
   5:   c3                      ret
```

I'm using GNU assembler (GNU Binutils) 2.25 (`x86_64-pc-cygwin').

**Question**:
Why is there an extra one qword offset (8bytes) in the memory operand QWORD PTR [rcx+0x8]? I expect mov rax,QWORD PTR [rcx].

I must be doing something wrong. So I cross-checked with another respected assembler Yasm and ran:

```
yasm -f x64 -o code2.obj --parser=gas code.asm
objdump -Mintel -d code2.obj > code2.asm
```

The content of code2.asm is:

```
code2.obj:     file format pe-x86-64
Disassembly of section .text:
0000000000000000 <somecode>:
   0:   cd 03                   int    0x3
   2:   48 8b 01                mov    rax,QWORD PTR [rcx]
   5:   c3                      ret
```

With regard to the memory operand, this is what I expected. How can I instruct GNU to do the same?

Comment: `qword` instead of `qword ptr` is NASM syntax. GAS unfortunately doesn't error on it, and has this "failure mode" because it allows `123[reg]` as address syntax.  I think there are also some SO Q&As about MASM itself having plain `dword` be the constant `4`, which also seems terrible.  Especially for MASM, it has keywords like `typeof` to turn a typename into a size for `add edi, typeof foo`.  Poor design IMO.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to write `mov rax, qword ptr [rcx]`. Apparently `qword` by itself resolves to the size, ie. `8`, so your code assembled as `mov rax, 8[rcx]`. Indeed, `mov rax, qword` also assembles as `mov rax, 8`.

It's funny how your "cross check" used the proper syntax :)

Comment: Brilliantly simple, this makes sense and it works, thanx. This is a real bug magnet. There ought to have been some warning...